# Special rule in Siunitx for percentages

Tags: siunitx, percent-sign

The convention used at my workplace is to have spaces between numbers and units except percentages.
Is there a way to create such an exception for a single unit throughout the document using the siunitx package?

Here is my MWE:

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[alsoload=synchem,%
                    range-phrase=--%
                    ]{siunitx}
        \sisetup{range-units=single}
        \sisetup{separate-uncertainty}
        \sisetup{detect-all}
        \DeclareSIUnit\weight{w}
        \DeclareSIUnit\volume{v}
        \sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{\cdot}}}
        \begin{document}
        In a glass beaker, add sodium hydroxide (\SI{1}{\gram}) and gently pour deionised water (\SI{40}{\milli\liter}). 

    Let the solution mix on the magnetic stirrer for \SI{120}{\second}.
    
    Now carefully add more water to raise the volume to \SI{100}{\milli\liter} to produce a \SI{1}{\percent} \si{\weight\per\volume} solution.
    
    Is there a way to make \SI{1}{\percent} look like 1\% ?
     \end{document}
```

Comment: IMO percent *is* a unit and should get the same spacing as the other units. We are just used to seeing 1% all over because people did not adhere to this rule

Comment: The BIPM list percent, hence I treat it as a unit in `siunitx`

Comment: I went against the grain using LaTeX instead of MS Word in my group. I ain't arguing over stuff like this.

Comment: @daleif IMHO, percent can also be interpreted as a plain constant number, i.e ``% := 10^{−2}``. (No need to involve the concept of a dimensionless unit). So take ``a := 10^{−2}`` instead. Would you still write ``3 a``? :) I think ``3%`` looks slightly better in this case but a "thin space" is not too shabby either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can re-declare the unit such that it applies a dedicated setting for the spacing. Getting the character means we have a little bit of work to do

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{%}
\catcode`\%=14\relax
\begin{document}

\SI{10}{\gram} but \SI{10}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

In v3, the option name has been updated to `quantity-product`: the above works with both v2 and v3.

Comment: Is it necessary to change the catcode of %? Can you write instead `\DeclareSIUnit[number-unit-product = ]\percent{\%}` without messing with catcodes?

Comment: @SergioLlorente Yes and no - it will work in most cases but using the 'real' character has advantage under some (unusual) circumstances. As I set things up in `siunitx` to be as robust as I can, I favour inserting a real `%` (I do it slightly differently in the code)